# Sorting file names by numeric value

Tags: perl, sorting, filenames, numerical

Preamble: I hate to ask questions like this, but I'm stuck with it and just learning Perl... seems like an easy task but I don't know where to look.

I have a folder with lots of xml-files that are all named ".xml".
I need to process those files in their numeric order, so "9123.xml" should come before "2384747.xml".
I have successfully sorted the list alphabetically with this:

```
opendir(XMLDIR,$xmldirname);
my @files = sort {$a cmp $b} readdir(XMLDIR);
```

but this isn't what I need.

I also tried

```
my @files = sort {$a <=> $b} readdir(XMLDIR);
```

which obviously fails because the filenames contain ".xml" and are not numeric as a whole.

Could someone open their heart and save me a week of browsing the Perl manuals?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting a directory in perl, taking numbers into account](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960488/sorting-a-directory-in-perl-taking-numbers-into-account)

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: I looked at that question, but they are looking only for the highest number. If a solution from that question applies to my problem, I do not understand which one or why or how.

Comment: See the [second solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2960767/176646). It shows how to write a custom sort routine that compares only the numeric part of a string. You only need to tweak the regex slightly.

Comment: And [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11730284/how-to-compare-filenames-in-perl) is an even better one. The accepted answer shows how to sort filenames naturally (i.e. taking into consideration both the alpha and the numeric parts).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Despite your claim, `sort { $a <=> $b } readdir(XMLDIR)` works. When Perl treats the string `2384747.xml` as a number (as `<=>` does), it is treated as having the value `2384747`.

```
$ perl -wE'say 0+"2384747.xml"'
Argument "2384747.xml" isn't numeric in addition (+) at -e line 1.
2384747
```

Of course, those warnings are a problem. The solution you accepted tries to remove them, but fails to remove all of them because it doesn't take into account that `readdir` will return `.` and `..`. You gotta remove the files you don't want first.

Here are two simple solutions:

```
my @files =
   sort { no warnings 'numeric'; $a <=> $b }
      grep { /^(\d)\.xml/ }
         readdir(XMLDIR);

my @files =
   sort { ( $a =~ /(\d+)/ )[0] <=> ( $b =~ /(\d+)/ )[0] }
      grep { /^(\d)\.xml/ }
         readdir(XMLDIR);
```

In this particular case, you can optimize your code:

```
my @files =
   map { "$_.xml" }             # Recreate the file name.
      sort { $a <=> $b }        # Compare the numbers.
         map { /^(\d)\.xml/ }   # Extract the number from desired files.
            readdir(XMLDIR);
```

The simplest and fastest solution, however is to use a natural sort.

```
use Sort::Key::Natural qw( natsort );

my @files = natsort grep !/^\.\.?/, readdir(XMLDIR);
```

Comment: Thank you for the introduction to [`Sort::Key::Natural`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sort::Key::Natural).  I've promoted the usage of [`Sort::Naturally`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sort::Naturally) a lot, but came by a couple of bugs in its implementation lately that I've been unable to resolve.  Am tempted to simply go back and replace all my references with this alternative module, but I'll probably play around with it some more first.

Comment: @Miller, I wasn't promoting a specific module; I've never used either. But glad it helped :)

Comment: Thanks ikegami. You're right of course. I didn't know that the original code would have worked, too, and simply ignored the warnings for the ./.. in the new solution. But I'll definitely try to go your route, because I don't like unresolved problems. They tend to come back while you sleep and bite you were it hurts :)

Answer (score 2):

You are actually pretty close.  Just strip off the ".xml" when inside your compare:

```
opendir(XMLDIR,$xmldirname);
my @files = sort {substr($a, 0, index($a, '.')) <=> substr($b, 0, index($b, '.'))} readdir(XMLDIR);
```

Comment: That is what I was looking for... seems pretty obvious now that I see it :)

Comment: Note that this will warn because it doesn't take into account that `readdir` will return `.` and `..`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `<=>` cannot work on something that is not *entirely* a number, in fact if you [`use warnings;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) you would get a message similar to this at run-time:

> Argument "11139.xml" isn't numeric in sort at testsort.pl line 9.

What you *can* do is separate out the filename from the extension, sort numerically on the filename then re-combine the extensions in. This can be done fairly straightforward with a [`Schwartzian transform`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform):

```
use strict;
use warnings; 

use Data::Dumper; 

# get all of the XML files
my @xml_files = glob("*.xml");

print 'Unsorted: ' . Dumper \@xml_files; 
@xml_files = map  { join '.', @$_ }              # join filename and extension
             sort { $a->[0] <=> $b->[0] }        # sort against filename
             map  { [split /\./] } @xml_files;   # split on '.'
print 'Sorted: ' . Dumper \@xml_files; 

__END__
Unsorted: $VAR1 = [
          '11139.xml',
          '18136.xml',
          '28715.xml',
          '6810.xml',
          '9698.xml'
        ];
Sorted: $VAR1 = [
          '6810.xml',
          '9698.xml',
          '11139.xml',
          '18136.xml',
          '28715.xml'
        ];
```

Comment: This seems like a solid solution. My Perl isn't yet as fluid as to allow me to understand exactly what's going on there.... so I'll accept the other question for now but I'll try to figure out what you did there...

Comment: Well, you read the expression for bottom to top. First for every xml filename, split that filename on a period ('.') and wrap that in an arrayref. This will take something like '1214.xml' and make `['1234','xml']`. Second for each of those arrayrefs you created sort by the zeroth element (which is the numeric filename). Third for each arrayref that has been sorted join the filename and extension back together using a period ('.').

Comment: @jackthehipster The wikipedia page linked in this answer does a pretty good job of explaining it, too.  The advantage of this solution is that it can be more efficient for larger data sets, since it computes all of the values for comparison once.  Since my solution (above) does this computation inside the compare block, it happens over and over again each time a compare is done.  This will not be an issue in your case, though, because your data set is small and the computation is not expensive.  Keep the Schwartzian Trasform in your back pocket, though - it is a good trick.

Comment: @hunter: I read up on the Schwartzian Transform now and it is easier than it looked at first sight. Thanks for introducing me to the concept.

Answer (score 1):

```
my @files =  sort {
    my ($x) = split /\./, $a;
    my ($y) = split /\./, $b;
    $x <=> $y
} readdir(XMLDIR);
```

Or without the temporary variables:

```
my @files =  sort {(split /\./, $a)[0] <=> (split /\./, $b)[0]} readdir(XMLDIR);
```

Comment: I knew that there had to be some way to do that with a regex inside the sort, and now I know how it's done. Thanks.