# What is this Perl syntax construct?

Tags: perl, sorting, syntax

I have a follow up question to my earlier post [Sorting file names by numeric value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25206041/sorting-file-names-by-numeric-value).

The solution was this piece of code:

```
opendir(XMLDIR,$xmldirname);
my @files = sort {substr($a, 0, index($a, '.')) <=> substr($b, 0, index($b, '.'))} readdir(XMLDIR);
```

I don't really understand what the whole sort {...} in front of the readdir is doing, or rather, HOW it is doing what it is doing. Of course I can see that two values are compared to each other. But what kind of syntax construct is this whole thing? Where is $a and $b coming from? Under what heading could I look that up in a Perl book? Is this a special thing that works only with sort {} or are there other ways of using this construct?

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html

Comment: It looks like it is creating a list of directory/file names numeric sorted by text in front of the first "." char. Hopefully this is the file extension delimiter, but it may not be. See http://www.perlfect.com/articles/sorting.shtml for more info

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because its answer is in the doc: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html

Comment: Nearly everything in programming is already explained in some docs. This is an legitimate programming question, so don't understand highvoted offtopic comment. Or the only _correct_ questions are where you can say: your solution is total fail, see how my oneliner greatly works?!

Comment: @kobame With respect, the information to answer this question isn't in some hard-to-find, obscure doc.  It's in the rudimentary documentation for the keyword `sort`.  Beginner questions are definitely welcome.  However, if the OP does not refer to the specific concept in the documentation that they're having trouble understanding or give an indication that they're even aware of the docs, then it is a better use of our time to refer them to the docs first.  They are welcome to come back with a more specific question afterwords.

Comment: I agree that I could have checked the docs first, however my question was not about the sort part, but about that to me weird reverse-pipe-like syntax. As I understand it now (not sure if I'm correct) is that it is at core a call like sort(somelistreturningfunc()) without the "()" with an ad-hoc code block in between that works like an argument to the sort function... but I'm still not sure what that kind of thing is... still trying to understand the answers.

Comment: @Miller: Sorry if I was unclear in my question, but I did try to be as specific as possible about what I'm not understanding here. It is not the comparison or the substr(), but the way that sort(), the codeblock {} and the following readdir() are connected. Usually, you'd see something like: sortedList = sort(readdir(),{comparatorcode}), if I understand the concept correctly. I'm unsure as to whether this is some special thing regarding only built-ins like sort, or if there is some Perl-construct in play that I fail to understand. It now seems prototypes have something to do with it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The adopted syntax of [`sort`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) is

```
sort BLOCK LIST
```

The expression represented by `LIST` is to return the list of values to sort. This is `readdir(XMLDIR)` in your case. It returns the list of the names of the files in the directory.

The `BLOCK` is the interesting part. It represents code in curlies that's called by the sorting algorithm to compare to of the elements to sort. The elements to compare are provided as `$a` and `$b`, and the code should evaluate to one of the following:

- A negative value if `$a` should be placed before `$b`,
- Zero if it doesn't matter matter where `$a` should be placed relative to `$b`, or
- A positive value if `$a` should be placed after `$b`.

`substr($a, 0, index($a, '.'))` extracts the portion of the file name before the first `.`. In this case, that extracts the number in the file name.

Then, the numbers extracted from the two file names are compared numerically by `<=>`, retuning `-1`, `0` or `+1` as described above.

---

Note that your code will warn because it doesn't take into account that `readdir` will return `.` and `..`. I addressed this by adding an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25246502/589924) to your original question.

Comment: Thanks ikegamie... I was maybe a little unclear in my question. I perfectly understand the substr() and sorting part (I'm a programmer), I just never saw a construct like that in the languages I used. I would have expected something like: sortedList = sort(readdir(),{comparator-class or code});

Comment: @jackthehipster, It's almost the same. The argument order is different, and the `,` is omitted between the compare code and the list. Also, while the parens around the arguments are allowed, they are rarely used.

Answer (score 4):

This is invoking [`sort`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) with a [block](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Basic-BLOCKs) argument. Blocks are used in several other Perl built ins including [`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) and [`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html).

A block argument is a way of defining your own code for the function to execute. `sort` uses the block to compare two values from the list being sorted, represented by `$a` and `$b`.

Using [prototypes](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes), you can define your own subroutines to work in a similar manner:

```
sub block_exec(&@) {
    my $block = shift;

    for (@_) {
        &$block;
    }
}

block_exec { print "block! $_\n"; } (1..10);
```

Answer (score 1):

Under what heading could I look that up in a Perl book?

Under 'sort'

http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html

That line is defining a custom method of comparing the two values (used to create the sorted list) which is different from the default comparisons. $a and $b are the two values being compared at a time in the sort.

Answer (score 1):

`$a` and `$b` are provided by `sort` to the comparison function passed to it. `sort` acts on an array, which is produced in this instance by `readdir`. `sort` repeatedly applies the unnamed comparison routine to the entries in the array, rearranging them until they're in order.

Answer (score 1):

Doing this: sort @arrayofnumbers
Is the same as: sort { $a cmp $b } @arrayofnumbers

Where $a and $b are the two items being compared at each step of the sort.
The return value of the block of code needs to be an integer where 0 means that the items are the same, <0 means that $a is less than $b, and >0 means that $a is greater than $b. Usually this is done with "cmp" for strings and <=> for numbers.

So the part that is confusing you, the stuff between the braces, is really just a block of code that will return -1, 0, or +1 depending on how you want the two items to compare.

You can do a lot of stuff in there, eg you can see the order of the compares by doing something like this:

`sort { print "$a cmp $b = ".($a cmp $b)."\n"; return $a cmp $b } (2,19,29,39);`

Yielding:
2 cmp 19 = 1
29 cmp 39 = -1
19 cmp 29 = -1
29 cmp 2 = 1

One thing that gets folks is that the default compare is a string compare.
So if you do:

`print join(',', sort 2,19,39,29)."\n";`

You'll get : 19,2,29,39

To do an integer compare you need to do:

`sort { $a <=> $b } (2,19,39,29)`

Comment: So basically, that block is like an argument passed to the sort function, something like a Comparator in Java or a code-block in the good old Clipper? And the missing parenthesis are just optional? I would have expected sortedList = sort(readdir(),sortingCode) or similar...